# What key on a Mac keyboard corresponds to the ⇥ symbol?

Tags: mac

I was looking at 
[PyCharm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/changing-indentation.html) which says the following:

> To change indentation of a text fragment, do one of the following
>
> On the main menu, choose Edit | Indent Selection / Edit | Unindent Selection.
>   Press ⇥ / ⇧⇥.

What is the ⇥ key on the Mac? I don't see this symbol on the keyboard.

Comment: The ⇥ symbol is very effectively searchable.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

<kbd>tab</kbd>

Comment: +1 for the shortest correct answer I've seen for a long time ;)

Comment: +1 for formatting as a key, making this even more perfect.

Answer (score 25):

#### Press ⇥ / ⇧⇥.

Firefox on Windows displays the following:

[image]

---

#### What is the ⇥ key on the mac, I can't find such a key on the keyboard?

[image]

On other Mac keyboards that key is labelled <kbd>tab</kbd>

[image]

Comment: There's nothing wrong with his browser. Inspect that HTML element on that website. They've designed it for different browsers on different platforms to display different things.

Comment: Also, the difference between the Apple keyboards you've pictured isn't between "older" and "newer" keyboards, it's variations between keyboard layouts for different countries/languages/regions.

Comment: Generally even though they're not labeled Mac users are expected to know the key symbols (they appear in e.g. menu shortcut labels even in the US, and on the on-screen keyboard) - even oddball ones like ⎋.

Comment: @Random832: The last symbol clearly meaning "cycle power at 10 o'clock".

Comment: @JS. Or even "Escape" which is the actual meaning ... see the list in one of the other answers.

Answer (score 24):

I've had similar problems interpreting Mac keyboard shortcuts, and I found the following list to be useful:

[image: Menu Symbols]

Image source: http://www.danrodney.com/mac/

Comment: There's a standard for such symbols.  It's [ISO/IEC 9995-7](https://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail?csnumber=51640).  Apple keyboard engravings are quite close to it.  So are some DIN 2137-1 keyboards and some Canadian keyboards (per [governmental requirements](https://www.tresor.gouv.qc.ca/fr/ressources-informationnelles/architecture-dentreprise-gouvernementale/standards-et-normes/standard-sur-le-clavier-quebecois-sgqri-001)).

Answer (score 13):

Looking at the source for that page, it shows the following code (indentation mine)

```
<kbd 
    data-default="Tab" 
    data-default_for_gnome="Tab" 
    data-default_for_kde="Tab" 
    data-default_for_xwin="Tab" 
    data-emacs="Tab" 
    data-visual_studio="Tab" 
    data-netbeans_6.5="N/A" 
    data-eclipse="Tab" 
    data-mac_os_x_10.5_="⇥" 
    data-mac_os_x="⇥" 
    data-eclipse_mac_os_x="⇥" 
    data-intellij_idea_classic_os_x="N/A" 
    data-xcode="N/A" 
    data-resharper="N/A" 
    data-resharper_osx="N/A"
>
Tab
</kbd>
```

Judging by this, I'd say your browser is doing exactly what it was told, and that they definitely intended for you to use the tab key.